# How to get cookie's expire time

Tags: php, cookies

When I create a cookie, how to get cookie's expire time?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/486298-get-cookie-expiry-time

Comment: What do you mean by getting a cookie’s expiration time? Do you want to know how to calculate it? Or how to retrieve it from an already set cookie?

Comment: You may use `Cookie::parse($cookieHeader)` with https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie and `ResponseHeader::get('Set-Cookie')` if you don't know how to get the cookie header otherwise.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is difficult to achieve, but the cookie expiration date can be set in another cookie. This cookie can then be read later to get the expiration date. Maybe there is a better way, but this is one of the methods to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the way. This is what Microsoft says: "The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies. Therefore, although you can read the name and value of a cookie, you cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time. When the browser sends cookie information to the server, the browser does not include the expiration information." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 113):

Putting an encoded json inside the cookie is my favorite method, to get properly formated data out of a cookie.
Try that:

```
$expiry = time() + 12345;
$data = (object) array( "value1" => "just for fun", "value2" => "i'll save whatever I want here" );
$cookieData = (object) array( "data" => $data, "expiry" => $expiry );
setcookie( "cookiename", json_encode( $cookieData ), $expiry );
```

then when you get your cookie next time:

```
$cookie = json_decode( $_COOKIE[ "cookiename" ] );
```

you can simply extract the expiry time, which was inserted as data inside the cookie itself..

```
$expiry = $cookie->expiry;
```

and additionally the data which will come out as a usable object :)

```
$data = $cookie->data;
$value1 = $cookie->data->value1;
```

etc. I find that to be a much neater way to use cookies, because you can nest as many small objects within other objects as you wish!

Comment: I also think this is the better answer (or strategy). Why create another cookie when you can use the same cookie to store expiry data?

Comment: Absolutely clever... I wish I could award more rep than allowed. 1+!

Comment: and by adding some kind of signature you could even prevent the user changing the expiry date

Comment: At the time I gave that answer, it was useful because json encode/decode is easily handled by php or javascript, so if you want to read if from server or client side its the same. Whereas serialize, needs an added function in javascript.. And serialize takes up a bit more space. Anyway that's a choice as you wish, the solution is just to encode the expiry inside the cookie data, anyway you want it ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can set your cookie value containing expiry and get your expiry from cookie value.

```
// set
$expiry = time()+3600;
setcookie("mycookie", "mycookievalue|$expiry", $expiry);

// get
if (isset($_COOKIE["mycookie"])) {
  list($value, $expiry) = explode("|", $_COOKIE["mycookie"]);
}
```

// Remember, some two-way encryption would be more secure in this case. See: https://github.com/qeremy/Cryptee

Answer (score 6):

When you create a cookie via PHP die Default Value is 0, from the manual:

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie
>   will expire at the end of the session
>   (when the browser closes)

Otherwise you can set the cookies lifetime in seconds as the third parameter:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

But if you mean to get the remaining lifetime of an already existing cookie, i fear that, is not possible (at least not in a direct way).

Answer (score 3):

It seems there's a list of all cookies sent to browser in array returned by php's `headers_list()` which among other data returns "**Set-Cookie**" elements as follows:

`Set-Cookie: cooke_name=cookie_value; expires=expiration_time; Max-Age=age; path=path; domain=domain`

This way you can also get deleted ones since their value is **deleted**:

`Set-Cookie: cooke_name=deleted; expires=expiration_time; Max-Age=age; path=path; domain=domain`

From there on it's easy to retrieve expiration time or age for particular cookie. Keep in mind though that this array is probably available only **AFTER** actual call to `setcookie()` has been made so it's valid for script that has already finished it's job. I haven't tested this in some other way(s) since this worked just fine for me.

This is rather old topic and I'm not sure if this is valid for all php builds but I thought it might be helpfull.

For more info see:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Answer (score 1):

To get cookies expire time, use this simple method.

```
<?php

//#############PART 1#############
//expiration time (a*b*c*d) <- change D corresponding to number of days for cookie expiration
$time = time()+(60*60*24*365);
$timeMemo = (string)$time;

//sets cookie with expiration time defined above
setcookie("testCookie", "" . $timeMemo . "", $time);

//#############PART 2#############
//this function will convert seconds to days.
function secToDays($sec){

    return ($sec / 60 / 60 / 24);

}
//checks if cookie is set and prints out expiration time in days
if(isset($_COOKIE['testCookie'])){

    echo "Cookie is set<br />";
    if(round(secToDays((intval($_COOKIE['testCookie']) - time())),1) < 1){
        echo "Cookie will expire today.";
    }else{
        echo "Cookie will expire in " . round(secToDays((intval($_COOKIE['testCookie']) - time())),1) . " day(s)";
    }

}else{
    echo "not set...";
}
```

?>

You need to keep **Part 1 and Part 2 in different files**, otherwise you will get the same expire date everytime.