# How to read cookie expiry time in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get cookie's expire time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203225/how-to-get-cookies-expire-time)

Hi, How can i read cookie expiry time in PHP

Thanks.

Comment: make a quick search on SO there are a lot of duplicate

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unless you store it elsewhere with your own mechanisms. Epxiry is a write-only field for cookies. Only the name and value of a cookie can be read once set. If the cookie is readable, it's not expired--that's all you get to know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the cookie expiry time, because browsers do not send it to your server, only the value of cookies. Browsers send cookies back to the server in a HTTP header like this;

```
Cookie: cookieName=cookieValue
```

The most common method of preventing cookies from expiring is setting an expiry date way in the future.

Comment: I dont want to expire. I want to know when cookie get created. 1 option i know is to make JS string of cookie name/time and send through ajax call. But thats too long process. Need shortcut.