# PHP getting expiring time of a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Can I get the expiring time of a cookie which is already set?
For example, I have set a cookie:

```
setcookie("test_cookie","some value", time()+3600*24*30);
```

Now can i get the time when the test_cookie is expiring?
One option could be that when i set the test_cookie, i can set the expiring time in another cookie, but i'm wondering if there's alternative, better way without setting other cookie?

Thanks.

Comment: Cookies are controlled by the browser and the user. You can suggest a expiry time when you set a cookie, but there is not guarantee the the HTTP client will even accept the cookie. Just saying, so next to checking for the expiry time, check for cookie existence as we..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it in another cookie is the best method, that or simply appending it to the end of the data you're storing with a delimeter such as #.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the expiry time because the browser doesn't send it. So the olny way is to store the time somewhere in another cookie or in session maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [How to get cookie's expire time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203225/how-to-get-cookies-expire-time)

cookie expiration date can be set in another cookie.This cookie can then be read later to get the expiration date