# PHP cookie variable getting deleted between programs

Tags: php, session, cookies

I tried searching for this issue on this forum but could not get it. So making a new post. Request you to redirect me to the right solution if available.

Problem: I am trying to use Facebook login in my program using javascript SDK. Once the user's acceptance is validated, I am passing the user to a php program that validates whether email id is already registered, connects the accounts and redirects the user to his homepage.

I am trying to register the userid of the user in a cookie in my validation program. The problem is that when I do a var_dump on $_COOKIE on the last line of my validation program, I am able to see a variable called as userid but when I do the same on the first line of my homepage, I do not see the variable. The cookie variable is getting lost somewhere between the pages.

Both the pages have session_start() as their first line of code.

Thanks in anticipation.

Regards,
Himanshu

Code Added

```
setcookie("user", $user, time()-86400); 
setcookie("user", $user, time()+86400,"/"); 
setcookie("userid", $id, time()-86400); 
setcookie("userid", $id, time()+86400,"/"); 
setcookie("name", $fname, time()-86400); 
setcookie("name", $fname, time()+86400,"/"); 
setcookie("fb", '1', time()-86400); 
setcookie("fb", '1', time()+86400,"/"); 


if((!$_SESSION['where'])||($_SESSION['where'] == ''))
{
    header("Location: http://www.xyz.com/mypage.php"); 
}
else
{
header("Location: $url");
}
```

In mypage.php, first two lines are as under:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Hope it is clearer now

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: `session_start()` has absolutely nothing to do with any cookies other than the cookie storing session id.  Are the programs on the same domain?

Comment: The programs are on the same domain.

Comment: This is how I am setting up the cookie


setcookie("user", $user, time()-86400); 
setcookie("user", $user, time()+86400,"/");

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203225/how-to-get-cookies-expire-time about setting expiration on cookies. Are you setting an expiration date/time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php) in addition to setting the $_COOKIE variable?
`setcookie` writes to the cookie file while $_COOKIE is a just a state of what the user has as cookies on page load.

Simpler version : write with `setcookie`, read with $_COOKIE.
If you need the $_COOKIE to be accessible right now, just set $_COOKIE along with the setcookie call.

Example :

```
<?php
//write
    setcookie('name', $value, $expirationInSeconds);
    $_COOKIE['name'] = $value;
//read
    $id = $_COOKIE['name'];
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a code snippet. When I call the two pages separately and manually, I see the variable. When I allow the header to redirect the url, I do not see them.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi did you set correctly your domain in the setcookie?

In my code, I use this: 
`setcookie('LOGIN_DATA', $classData, time() + $expiration, '/', null, false, true);`

(`null` domain sets by default your website's domain name)