# Setting a cookie's value without changing the expiration date

Tags: php, cookies

I have some cookie that obviously keeps some information. I want to set its value, but keep the expiration date as it is (as not changing it at all). Is there an easier way than saving the expiration date on another cookie and then read from it? I tried searching and this is the only solution I found, but am quite sure there are other ways.

Comment: perhaps check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203225/how-to-get-cookies-expire-time for the work around mentioned by @paullb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible using the PHP functionality, but there is a workaround.

You can do this is to read in the original expiry date and when you set the cookie match it up so that the expiration date hasn't changed.

Comment: If it isn't possible, why say "the only way." Contradicted yourself there.

Comment: It isn't directly doable within the existing function set, but a workaround exists. Will update my wording.

Comment: I know, just stating for the wording. Could get confusing if that's all people read.

Comment: As I thought. I'll just create a new cookie that contains the original expiry date. Thanks! ;)